# Performing affine transformation on shapefile with OGR, GDAL or other command line tools

Tags: gdal, r, ogr2ogr, affine-transformation

Transformations with WKT or EPSG code are made easy with ogr2ogr, but are there tools for me to define my own affine transformation to apply to the coordinates of a shapefile?

Or, in general, is there a tool to apply a function to shapefile coordinates?

Further along this note, I also need to change coordinates in the shapefile based on a LUT.

Are there simple tools that exist which do this, or will I have to write such a utility myself?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. 
Please **[edit]** some extra info into the body of the question for clarification:
e.g. explain why/how you wish to change coordinates based on a look-up (which necessarily involves discrete data)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you happen to work in R, you can use the [vec2dtransf package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vec2dtransf/index.html) (which is mine :) ). You would simply need to load your Shapefiles into R using rgdal and define your affine transformation to apply it on the data. After such process, you can export your data to a transformed Shapefile also via rgdal. In vec2dtransf, affine transformations can be defined from coordinates or directly from parameters.

See [this post](https://geotux.tuxfamily.org/en/2012/05/07/similarity-and-affine-transformations-in-r/) for a detailed example.